# c# .net - Question about multiple Projects under same solution in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have project 1 and Project 2. If using File Upload feature in some Project1's code file I want to save the uploaded files in Project 2's folder. What should be the save path??
Like I gave the physical address as D://Project2/images/products/

but it says, I cant give physical path and that only virtual path will be accepted. What should be my saving path?

Please help me out. Thanks.

**@Peyman
how exactly wil I refer to this folder in my c# code?**

**@ Peyman 
I tried your solution..its creating the Upload folder in c:/inetpub or something and giving this error when I am running upload code "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Upload\images\products\Product1\"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create virtual folder in your IIS and point to the specific folder in second project. then when you want to upload any file save in Virtual Folder Url.

[image]

Comment: ok will do that but how exactly wil I refer to this folder in my c# code?

Comment: At first create instance for your first project in IIS, then under that site create virtual directory and point it to the specific folder under the second project and specify name for virtual directory such as "Upload". Then you can use this virtual name to upload the file and save it in second project folder. uploader.SaveAs("/Upload/filename.ext");

Comment: I tried your solution..its creating the Upload folder in c:/inetpub or something and giving this error when I am running upload code "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Upload\images\products\Product1\"

Comment: da ... you should use `Server.MapPath()` - you input a virtual path, and get the corresponding local path back ... you shouldn't use `/Upload/` either - the correct way would be `~/Upload/`